# MPJ Express hangs

Tags: ubuntu, arm, mpj-express

I am trying to run **MPJ Express** in cluster mode without the runtime as explained in **Appendix A** of [mpj linux guide](http://mpj-express.org/docs/guides/linuxguide.pdf)

I cannot use **runmpj.sh** script as my class has some command line arguments that I need to pass and this script doesn't accept that. So, my only bet is to run it with the command

**java -cp .:$MPJ_HOME/lib/mpj.jar World  mpj.conf niodev**

But when I do this, the console simply hangs as if waiting for more command line arguments and trying to add some more arguments doesn't seem to change anything. My platform is **ARM Cortex-A9** running Ubuntu Linaro. This machine is not supported by the mpj middleware that is why I cannot use **mpjboot** or **mpjrun** scripts.

Any idea about the possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of MPJ-Express uses Java Service Wrapper binaries to launch daemons on remote nodes. The current version (v0.38 I assume) does not have hard/soft float ABIs for ARM. Please wait for the next public release, I hope they will incorporate ARM support for that.